# Convert str to float python

Tags: python, type-conversion

Why does this throw an error : `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

```
frequencies.append(float(l[start+1:stop1].strip())) 
losses.append(float(l[stop1+5:stop2].strip()))
```

Doesn't the float() command parse values into the float type? Where am I wrong here? Both frequencies and losses are lists

This is the code:

```
def Capture():
impedance = 0 
losses = [] 
frequencies = [] 
Xtalk = []
start = 0
stop1 = 0
stop2 =0
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(user_input, '*.txt')):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
        for l in f.readlines(): 
            if l.startswith(' Impedance'): 
                v = l[12:-7] 
                impedance = float(v) 
            if l.startswith(' Xtalk'): 
                Xtalk.append(l[7:].strip()) 
            if l.startswith(' Loss per inch'): 
                start = l.find('@') 
                stop1 = l.find('GHz', start) 
                stop2 = l.find('dB', start) 
            frequencies.append(float(l[start+1:stop1].strip())) 
            losses.append(float(l[stop1+5:stop2].strip())) 
print(impedance, frequencies, losses, Xtalk)
```

It basically takes values from a text file and prints them onto the console 
And the text files look like this:

```
    Impedance = 71.28 ohms

Begin Post processing
Frequency multiplier = 1Hz
number of ports = 12
Start Frequency = 0
End Frequency = 40000000000
Number of Frequency points = 4001
Touchstone Output file = C:\Users\Aravind_Sampathkumar\Desktop\IMLC\BO\Output_TW_3.5-TS_3-core_h_2.xml_5000mil.s12p
Output format = Real - Imaginary
Loss per inch @ 2.500000e+00 GHz = -0.569 dB
Loss per inch @ 5 GHz = -0.997 dB
Xtalk #1 (Conductor 1  2):
    Step response Next= -0.56 mV
    Step response Fext peak @ 5 inches= 0.11 mV
Xtalk #2 (Conductor 5  6):
    Step response Next= -0.56 mV
    Step response Fext peak @ 5 inches= 0.11 mV
Finished post processing
```

Comment: What exactly is `l`?

Comment: Did you check each data input that is being passed in to float to ensure that you are in fact sending something exactly expected by the float method to properly convert it to a float? Can you provide a sample of what your data actually looks like?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: @Potato You're still not showing the actual data to know why the `float` method is failing. The problem is based on the data you are reading and how you are passing it to the methods you are using. I suggest removing all the work being done inside the `float` method and printing it on the line before to see what each entry will look like. It will help you troubleshoot this easier.

Comment: Wait let me get a snap of the text file too

Comment: @Potato Please don't take a screenshot, though. A small 'real' sample of the data would suffice.

Comment: Just show us the output of `print(repr(l), start, stop1,stop2))`

Comment: ("'\\n'", 0, 0, 0) is the output

Comment: And did you ensure that `l[stop1+5:stop2].strip()` in fact gives you exactly a string representing a float? Did you inspect the output already?

Comment: How do I verify if all values are strings?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure which is the format of variable.

string with comma can't be converted to float with "float()" parser

```
a = "1,2345"
float(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,2345'
a = "1.2345"
float(a)
1.2345
```